# not robust to control/controlling

Tags: gerund-vs-infinitive

I would like to say that a certain result is not robust after controlling for certain variables, like age or education.

That is, I obtained a certain result, but after I control for certain variables, the result vanishes.

Do I say:

> the result is not robust to *controls* for age, education, ...

or

> the result is not robust to *controlling* for age, education, ...

?

On Google I find 19,200 results for "not robust to controlling", and 14,600 results for "not robust to controls".

So it looks like both ways are possible?

Comment: I’d probably say “… not robust *after* controlling for … “

Comment: Or "... not robust after taking into account ..."

Comment: Could you not just say that the result "correlates directly with age/education/etc."

Comment: @JeffUK no that's kind of obvious. In empirical data you never have exactly 0 correlation